# Estimate the unique permutation of a vector that fits a desired spectral density

Tags: time-series, fourier-transform, spectral-analysis

Lets say I have a vector of 10,000 random data that follow a predefined distribution.

Is it possible to find the unique permutation of this vector (without modifying its values) that matches *as closely as possible* a prespecified spectral density (or periodgram) ? 
The power spectral phase can be ignored.

One very ugly solution solution could be the following: bruteforce all permutations, perform an FFT and compare the spectral density with the desired one.

Comment: Since almost all permutations will produce a white-noise-like FFT and since there is an astronomical number of possible permutations (more than $10^{1051299}$ of them), your very ugly solution won't work.  Could you explain what connection this question has with statistics or data analysis?  Maybe it should be migrated to a scientific computing or signal processing site.

Comment: What do we know about the 10,000 random data? Can we say that they are independently distributed and Gaussian?

Comment: We know the distribution of the data, we can assume that it is Gaussian and iid if it helps.
I know that my ugly solution does not work I was just trying to explain what I am looking for. I could not find a more appropriate site to ask, and i saw some relevant questions here. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The prespecified spectral density could probably be related to an autoregressive-moving-average (ARMA) time series model. You could try to see which ARMA model would generate a spectral density close to the prespecified one. Then you can simulate some data from the ARMA model using the 10,000 random data as the innovations. Then you can simply check the ordering of the random data in the simulated sample in order to get the indices of the permutation.

Comment: Can you give some more details about the context of your question or purposes? There may be other ways to address it without the need to search for this permutation.

Comment: Well the intention was to sample a 3 hourly timeseries with specified characteristics for simulation purposes: a) Statistical distribution (based on inverse transformation sampling), b) Correlation with specified correlation matrix and c) Spectral with based on an artificial PSD with 2-3 peaks according to the desired periodicity (e.g. weekly, daily). I have achieved the first two and my question refers to the third one.

Comment: The autocovariances and the spectral density contain the same information. If you managed to get b) then you should be able to get c) by translating the desired 
spectral density into the time domain. To do so you could apply the inverse Fourier transform on the specified spectral density in order to get the corresponding autocorrelation function.

Comment: Thank you javlacalle for your insight. Point _b)_ mentioned in my previous comment, does not refer to autocorrelations but to correlation between the three different timeseries. I will try to work out your idea of using a simulated timeseries as a seed to an ARMA model.